# Free memory when using geometry in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, polygon

This text was translated in Google Translate.

When using the geometry functions in SQL Server 2008 R2, I have noticed that my server memory is increasing, and I have no way to release used memory.

I have a table where we store the different **polygons** that cover the different neighborhoods of my city.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mapa_MSB (
  id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  zona varchar(50),
  GeogCol1 geometry,
  GeogCol2 AS [GeogCol1].[STAsText]()
)
```

So, I have a function whose parameters are the coordinates of a point in my city, and with this it returns the different polygons that point enters. With the coordinates I create my point using **geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(X, Y)', 4326)**

```
declare @geo geometry
declare @flete geometry
declare @result geometry

set @geo = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-100.35171446 25.66744965)', 4326)
```

Then I make a cursor to read all my polygons from my Mapa_MSB table, and I use the STIntersection function so that it returns me whether or not that point enters that polygon, the result is stored in a temporary memory, and at the end I perform a simple query to obtain the different polygons where there was an intersection.

```
declare @resultado_temporal table(
    resultado varchar(max),
    zona varchar(50))

declare @id int,
        @zona varchar(50),
        @GeogCol1 geometry
                
declare localiza_cursor cursor for
select id, zona, GeogCol1
from Zonas2.dbo.Mapa_MSB
        
open localiza_cursor

fetch next from localiza_cursor
into @id, @zona, @GeogCol1

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @flete = GeogCol1 from Zonas2.dbo.Mapa_MSB where id = @id    
    
    set @flete = @flete.MakeValid()
    
    if @flete.STIsValid() = 1
    begin
        select @result = @flete.STIntersection(@geo)
    
        insert into @resultado_temporal
        select @result.STAsText(), @zona
        where @result.STAsText() <> 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY'
    end
    
    fetch next from localiza_cursor
    into @id, @zona, @GeogCol1  
end

close localiza_cursor
deallocate localiza_cursor

select * from @resultado_temporal
```

Every time I use this procedure, the memory of my server is going up, **what can I do to optimize this procedure or so that the memory of the server does not go up?**

Comment: First of all, see if you can upgrade to a version of SQL Server that's still supported, unlike 2008 R2, which has been out of support for quite a while now. Second, try rewriting this cursor-based approach to a proper set-based query; there appears to be no reason to use a cursor here (something like `WITH g1 AS (SELECT id, zona, vg = GeogCol1.MakeValid() FROM Zonas2.dbo.Mapa_MSB), g2 AS (SELECT id, zona, intersect_result = vg.STIntersection(@geo) FROM g1 WHERE vg.STIsValid() = 1) SELECT id, intersect_result.STAsText(), zona FROM g2 WHERE intersect_result.STIsEmpty() = 0`).

Comment: Also, SQL Server is *supposed* to use as much memory as it can. Have you tried setting the Max Server Memory?

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to optimize the code, I found the book ***"Beginning Spatial with SQL Server 2008"***, where they recommend using the **Filter()** function, so I managed to optimize the code, being like this:

```
declare @geo geometry

set @geo = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-100.35171446 25.66744965)', 4326)

select GeogCol2, zona
from Zonas2.dbo.Mapa_MSB
where GeogCol1.MakeValid().Filter(@geo) = 1
```